# Why does porridge start steaming more after the hob is switched off?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, physical-chemistry, thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction

I have noticed that when I cook porridge in a saucepan, and stir it with a spatula, it only steams a little bit. But the moment I turn off the (gas) hob underneath, and keep stirring it with a spatula, suddenly a noticeably more steam starts coming out of the saucepan.

This seems counter-intuitive, because the heat source is no longer there. Is there an easy explanation for this phenomenon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you see of the "steam" is actually condensed water, i.e., more or less fine drops of liquid water.

Turning off the gas means that the temperature of the steam and air column above the pot decreases; therefore, more water condenses.

In reality, what you have is less and slowly rising steam—not more—so it starts to condense before it can be sucked into the aspiration fan or diffuse into the kitchen.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder whether, paradoxically, there is a temporary increase in the rate of heat entry to the bulk of the porridge when you turn off the gas. The reason would be that while you are heating, a relatively poorly conducting stationary layer of solid well-cooked porridge is continually forming on the very hot base of the saucepan, despite stirring. When you turn off the gas the saucepan bottom is no longer scorching hot and the stirring is effective in removing the poorly conducting layer.

A related effect, perhaps more important, is that fatter bubbles of steam will form on the relatively smooth saucepan bottom than would have formed on the stationary layer of porridge. Thus boiling might be more dramatic when the gas is first turned off and the stationary layer dispersed.

Comment: Thank you for the very nice answer. Would you say that in addition to your argument, @Alchimista's argument could also partially account for the phenomenon? Perhaps it is the combination of all three physical processes?

Comment: @JanStuller it is the other way around. Something like that might happen, surely it does if you look it as convection stopped. But it is a complement to my answer not viceversa. It is not true that you see more vapour, "you see less". More "fog" is a natural consequence of closing the gas, you have less evaporation/boiling, not more.

Comment: Now I have a dilemma which answer to accept :) I trust you, @Alchimista, but given Philip Wood's high reputation, do you mind if I wait for his input on this? :)

Comment: @JanStuller that is not under discussion. And waiting before accepting is OK as for better answer can be given. My answer is the answer, but this statement is of mine.... While in the specific case I am sure, in general we can always learn.

Comment: @JanStuller I like Alchimista's answer more than (I think) Alchimista likes mine. I'm a little surprised, though, that a significant drop in temperature of the steam and air column above the pot should occur so suddenly after turning off the gas. We need to do more research!

Comment: @JanStuller I think that, on this occasion, the votes say it all !

Comment: Ok, but pls don't delete your answer. I have still found it valuable and it's opened my mind about what might be going on at the bottom of the saucepan!

Comment: @PhilipWood it is not that I dislike the answer.... It seems the answer to "why stopping the heating causes bigger bubbles to pop" as for your idea plus a reduced convection might cause sacks of vapour to grow until they get their way to the surface.